# Android Emulator not sync with VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am having some issue when running a Xamarin.Forms application in the Android Emulator using Visual Studio 2015. At the beginning everything was working OK. Every time I did a change either in XAML or C#, when I rerun the emulator I can see the changes (without closing it).

Now, for some reason if I do the same, those changes are not applied in the Android Emulator. In order to see any change, I need to close the emulator and click the green play button again every time.
[image]

For example, if I want to change the FontColor of a label to be Blue instead of Black in XAML, before just clicking the restart button was enough to see the change. For any C# change, clicking the stop button and then the play button was enough as well.

[image]

Now, to see the same result I have to close the emulator and reload it again. Which take some time.

[image]

Has anyone have faced the same problem? Any help/ clue would be ver helpful?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart the emulator each time. This is a huge time sink. If anything it's possible that the XAML compilation process is not being taken into account each build and it's using the previous cache build. You may want to try simply removing the application from the Android emulator(Either by uninstalling or using `adb uninstall <package-name>` and redeploying to see if that fixes part of the issue. For the issue of deploys not overriding each other, I'm not sure if this is specific to the XAML compilation process or an inconsistency in the deploy.

Answer (score 0):

@MikePR

I suggest to get rid of the Hyper-V based VS Android Emulator and use the Intel HAXM 
native Emulator. I experienced much simular
issues with Hyper-V emulator, too.

Or much better get rid of any emulator and use
vysor.io and visualize your real device like an
emulator on your desktop. My personal favorit.
Hope it is helpful.

PS: Never in life use GenyMotion. That doesn't work in Remote Desktop Sessions and only runs
on windows machines with OpenGL 2.0 installed
and HAXM and Hyper-V disabled. I currently had that disappointing experience.

A really cool tool for XAML Preview is Gorilla Player!